# Testing mobile application based on GPS

Tags: mobile

We developed application based on GPS, google maps and location, now we make localization and I should test how our application will work in China.

Any tips?

My location is in Israel. How can I bring the device think that I'm at China?

Comment: Checkout this link:  [link](http://dandoonan.blogspot.in/2013/03/mock-locations.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the application on an emulator, it should give you a way to define location
2. Ask the developer to allow you to inject mock locations through some sort of API

2.1 Mocking can be done at the app level- i.e. don't read the location from the GPS

2.2 You did not mention a platform, but Android and I suppose iOS too have the possibility to mock a location through the native API

3. If you are concerned about using a real GPS signal then buy a GPS signal generator (at ~100K$ or more)
4. Fly to china ?

Answer (score 0):

@Talya Ostrovsky Lit -

1) You can use some application which can change your location, easily available on Google app store.  or you can search some more application
such as "hola"

2) Or you can you simulator and emulator for such testing.